# How can I improve this Ethernet differential pair?

Tags: pcb-design, differential, routing, kicad

This is my first 100 Mbit/s Ethernet project (I am doing it to learn more about differential signals).

I did two things that I don't know if are good or bad in this particular case.

One is to route under the signal transformer. It is only slightly on the border, but I didn't find any other way to route it, without using vias to swap the pair.

What do you think? It would be better to use vias (and an impedance mismatch), or route so close to the inductor?

Also, I tried the differential tools in [KiCad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KiCad), and I matched both pairs to the same length (otherwise, one track is about 6 mm longer). Is this a good practice for Ethernet?

This is a capture of the PCB right now:

[image]

This is the schematic that I am using. It uses the lan9512 reference schematic. To be honest, I am no idea of the impedance on my design. I am not sure if I have to use 50 ohm or 100 ohm.

[image]

I include the impedance calculation for a double sided PCB, FR4 1.6 mm height and 1.6 oz copper (35 µm)

As you can see, the track with is 0.8 mm!! - way too large.

[image]

This is the final version. Track with 1.6 mm, gap 0.16 mm (minimum in my cheap PCB provider).

[image]

Thank you everybody for this valuable master class. I will read a lot about differential pairs.

Comment: Is data polarity important to maintain in ethernet?

Comment: I would route the signal in a different way: move RX+ trace to the left, this opens more space between pin 8 and RX+ trace. Use this space to place RX- trace. The length match is achieved in a natural way.

Comment: You have to consider the width of trace and its single-ended impedance. What is it in your PCB design? If it is close to 50 Ohms, there is no need to put RX+ RX- traces near each other. If it differs more than 15% from 50 Ohms - you have to route RX+ RX- signal as a differential pair. Then your design is not acceptable, guess it is worse than the one with length mismatch.

Comment: @Andy: Lane reversal is available on some PHY receivers, but it is not mandated by specification (for any version, as far as I know).

Comment: How about the reversal happens on the other side of the transformer?

Comment: I included the schematic. How can I know the impedance required by my design?

Comment: good question, can I swap RX- and RX+ and CRX-/CRX+ in my schematic?

Comment: Why are you using a separate transformer? Look into a suitable "MAGJACK" type connector and get transformer and RJ45 all on the same footprint and save room on your PCB.

Comment: @michael: because my plan is to use 4 ports in the next version, and i didnt find 4 port magjacks at a reasonable price.

Comment: I would still use MagJacks and just put four of them side by side.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I were to suggest how to route this I would propose something more like this:

[image]

Comment: Clever picture editing gets my vote.

Comment: Definitely agree, length matching is only half the battle with diff pairs.  If you have the same length traces but each takes a radically different route across the board then it's quite possible for one of the traces will be subject to inductive/capacitive (etc) effects that the other trace is not.  @MichaelKaras' suggestion is preferable, because any inductive effects will be experienced equally by both traces and will be cancelled out by the way that diff pairs intrinsically work.

Comment: I see. the transformer could affect both traces, but the effect wont cause mayor problems. +1

Answer (score 4):

About impedance: you clearly need 100 Ohms differential, it is the same as 50 Ohms single wire. You have to use some "impedance calculator" (for example: https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/microstrip-impedance). The dielectric thickness goes from your PCB design. The copper thickness is typically 35 um, it has a little effect on results. The trace width and trace separation does matter for RF designs.

Comment: Another good tool is [Saturn PCB Toolkit](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit.htm).

Comment: Interestingly, USB2.0 and Ethernet (10/100 at least, not sure about GBE) have very similar characteristic impedance requirements, which makes life easier when you have both on a single design.  In my experience USB2.0 needs 90 Ohms +/-15% and Ethernet typically is around 100 Ohms, there is a handy window of overlap there.

Comment: Also, you can always ask your board manufacturer to do the impedance calcs for you when you submit the Gerbers to them.  This is a standard thing to ask for and they won't charge you for it (most likely).  In fact you can even ask them to change the trace width for you in order to meet the impedance you want.

Answer (score 3):

About length matching: This is not as important as one might think. 100MBit Ethernet uses a symbol rate of 125 MBaud/s, each symbol is 8 ns long. Compared to that, a 10 mm different routing length introduces a skew of (speed of signals in copper traces is roughly half the speed of light) 30 ps only, or less than 0.5%. While this slightly reduces the margin to get bit errors on the receiver, the influence is negligible.

I would rather focus on providing (roughly) the correct impedance. Without going for more expensive impedance controlled PCBs, the best rule of thumb is: Distance between both traces should be the same as their width and the distance to the next ground layer should be a bit more than the width of the two traces. E.g. 150um traces, 150um gap, 200-400um to ground layer (as is typical on a 4 to 8 layer PCB).

Comment: Ok, thank you, this answer helps me a lot!! This board is only 2 layers (I believe that 4 layers is way better, but this is only a test for myself). I am planning to dont use a ground plane under all differential traces (even usb ones).

Comment: I strongly advise to use ground plane below high speed traces.

Comment: @asdfex, I use 0.1 mm FR4 between Top high speed lines and next ground plane. The trace width for 50 Ohms (as I remember) is 0.16 mm. This works fine, I ordered impedance control several times - no need to change the width. The differential 100 Ohms line has width 0.15 mm and separation 0.15 mm. Using 0.2-0.4 mm dielectric leads to too thick PCB, even on 8 layers.

Comment: @Master 
Your differential 0.15/0.15 traces and 0.1mm dielectric gives about 80 Ohms impedance. My  0.15/0.15 and 0.2 yields a close to perfect 95 Ohms, even better with 0.1mm traces and gaps. My PCB producer has a default 8-layer stack of 180um separation between each of the layers, at a total stack height of 1.6mm.

Comment: @asdfex, did you measure the impedance or did you order the impedance control manufacturing process? I really wonder. The difference between your design and my design is, say, rather large. My design is not only based on calculations, it is verified several times by the impedance control process at PCB manufacturer. They told me no need to change the width as the impedance is 100 Ohms within few percent.

Comment: @Master, I didn't measure it, but it was the recommendation from the manufacturer and confirmed by Saturn PCB Tool.

Answer (score 0):

At the lengths and the speeds your board will see, it probably won't make much difference. At 100Mbit that's only 50MHz of bandwidth, length matching traces is usually not an issue until the length difference becomes a meaningful fraction of the wavelength (which at 50MHz is 6 meters, even the 9th harmonic is still over half a meter). I wouldn't worry about it.